# Iterating backwards over an array throwing exception

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make an add method that works like long addition, so I want to start the addition from the end and work my way backwards so I can get the carrys right and etc. So I am currently trying to start working backwards over the array.
For example what im trying to do.
two arrays with the character 123456789
and i want to add them starting at 9 + 9 then move to 8+8

So I'm pretty sure I'm using the right way to iterate backwards over an array, but everytime I try I get just the runtime error, index out of bounds, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be great, I just cant figure out why it keeps throwing the exception.

```
-(MPInteger *) add: (MPInteger *) x
{

    NSMutableArray *a = self->intString;
    NSMutableArray *b = x->intString;
    NSMutableArray *c = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];



    //for (int i  = 0; i < [a count]; i++) {
    for (NSInteger i = [a count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int num = 10;
        NSNumber *ourNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:num];
        NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[a objectAtIndex:i] intValue] + [[b objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
        if ([total intValue] >= [ourNum intValue]) {
            total = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([total intValue] - [ourNum intValue])];
            [c addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:([total intValue])]];
        } else {
            [c addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[a objectAtIndex:i] intValue]+[[b objectAtIndex:i] intValue]]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", c[i]);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: These days is `c[i]` valid syntax for `NSArray` objects in ObjectiveC? Because you used to have to do `[c objectAtIndex:i]`.

Comment: Break apart the `total` line into two temps and a simple add, then you can see precisely which operation fails.  Note that you are assuming that a and b are the same size, and you will get a failure if they are not.  Also note that you will stop one digit too soon.

Comment: @AlexWayne - Yes, with the latest Xcode "standard" array indexing notation is supported.  And a bunch of other whiz-bang features (that further confuse you if they are all mixed together).

Comment: @AlexWayne yes, `c[i]` on `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s has been in for quite some time now.

Comment: You don't appear to be doing a carry, when the digit sum exceeds 9.  Hard to tell with the poor formatting, though.

Comment: All the operations work if I iterate forwards, it's just when I iterate forwards, its just the iterating backwards I have a problem with @Hot Licks I also havent added in the carry part yet.

Comment: Are a and b always of equal length??

Comment: @ They won't always be, but at the moment for testing they are.

Comment: They must be, or you will get errors.  Note that you can use `@[someNumber]` in place of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:someNumber]`.  Will make the code much neater and easier to read.  (I don't offhand know of a corresponding unboxing operation, though.)

Comment: (There's not much to be gained by trying to cram so much on one line, and a lot to lose.  Break up your lines into short expressions and temp assignments.)

Comment: @HotLicks I believe you mean `@(someNumber)`. `@[]` is an array literal. The unboxing method would be `intValue`, `boolValue`, etc. There is no syntactic sugar for unboxing.

Comment: @BergQuester - You are correct -- I meant `@(someNumber)` -- Still haven't used these much myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's clean up this code.

```
- (MPInteger *)add:(MPInteger *)x {
    NSMutableArray *a = self->intString;
    NSMutableArray *b = x->intString;
    NSMutableArray *c = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

    for (NSInteger i = [a count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int num = 10;
        NSNumber *ourNum = @(num);
        NSNumber *total = @([a[i] intValue] + [b[i] intValue]);

        if ([total intValue] >= [ourNum intValue]) {
            total = @([total intValue] - [ourNum intValue]);
            [c addObject:@([total intValue])];
        } else {
            [c addObject:@([a[i] intValue] + [b[i] intValue])];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", c[i]);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Next, let's remove redundant/duplicate code.

```
- (MPInteger *)add:(MPInteger *)x {
    NSMutableArray *a = self->intString;
    NSMutableArray *b = x->intString;
    NSMutableArray *c = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

    for (NSInteger i = [a count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int num = 10;
        NSNumber *total = @([a[i] intValue] + [b[i] intValue]);

        if ([total intValue] >= num) {
            total = @([total intValue] - num);
        }

        [c addObject:total];

        NSLog(@"%@", c[i]);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Now we can clearly see all of the issues.

1. You're going from `[a count] - 1` to `1`. You should be going all the way to 0.
2. `a` and `b` might have different sizes, so if you only do `[a count] - 1` to `0`, then if for example `[b count] < [a count]`, you'll get an index out of bounds error when you try to access `b[i]`.
3. You're adding stuff to the end of `c`, but you should be adding it to the beginning of `c` since you're iterating backwards.
4. You don't store the carry anywhere.
5. You are accessing `c[i]`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with an empty array 'c', and you NSLog c[i] which is obviously out of bounds on the first iteration.